# Inserting data into a table in WordPress database using WordPress $wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am starting out plugin development and have followed the tutorials on the WordPress Codex sites. I am now stuck - I have a database called "wp_imlisteningto", where the `wp_` was inserted using:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "imlisteningto";
```

When the plugin is activated.

The database itself has three columns, set up when the plugin is activated:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
id mediumint(9) AUTO_INCREMENT,
album VARCHAR(50),
artist VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY  KEY (id)
);";
```

I am trying to insert data (by creating a new row) into this database from a php form.

Within the WordPress admin, I create a new page which has the very simple form:

```
<form action="/wp-content/plugins/listeningto/formhtml.php" method="post">
Album: <input type="text" name="album" />
Artist: <input type="text" name="artist" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Which as you can see calls `formhtml.php`, which is:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'album' => $_POST['album'], 'artist' => $_POST['artist'] ), array( '$s', '$s' ) );
?>
```

When I submit the form, I get an `Error 500.0` when running the plugin in Worpdress on `IIS7.0`, and a `"Page Not Found"` when running on another web server which runs `apache`.

If I change `formhtml.php` to:

```
<?php

echo $_POST['album'];
echo $_POST['artist'];

?>
```

Works fine - I get the album and artist that I put in the form. Obviously something I'm doing wrong when inserting the data (in a new row) into the database.

Any thoughts as to what that might be?

UPDATE

Ok, so if I update `formhtml.php` with this:

```
<?php
require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "imlisteningto";
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'album' => $_POST['album'], 'artist' => $_POST['artist'] ), array( '$s', '$s' ) );
?>
```

I no longer get an error message, but data still doesn't get put into the database.

**UPDATE 2**

**This worked for me:**

```
<?php
require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "imlisteningto";
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'album' => $_POST['album'], 'artist' => $_POST['artist'] ) );
?>
```

as did this:

```
<?php
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "imlisteningto";
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'album' => $_POST['album'], 'artist' => $_POST['artist'] ) );
?>
```

So, for some reason `$wpdb` was not working unless I required either `wp-config` or `wp-load.php`. If include `wp-load.php`, `$wpdb` gets values and all is well.

Comment: require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php'); should work as well. ABSPATH is defined @wp-load.php

Answer (score 5):

including

```
require_once('../../../wp-config.php');
```

worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'album' => "$_POST['album']", 'artist' => "$_POST['artist']" ) );
?>
```

Ex :

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->insert($table_name , array('chart_name' => "Line Chart" ,'chart_type' => "trends",'status' => 0));

?>
```

Comment: Hi Ajay thanks for the reply - no, that didn't work either. However, I have updated my post with what worked for me.

Comment: @MattyRasker Is it works ? for more info https://snipt.net/ajaypatel_aj/wordpress-crud-queries/

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out by now, but no one addressed it here. Your sample code has '$s' in the 3rd parameter (2nd array), but that should be '%s' because it's for value-formatting. The WP Codex says [http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb] that this format parameter for $wpdb->insert() is optional.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $global $wpdb;      
  $table_name1 = $wpdb->prefix.'php_crud';  
    
  $data_insert= array(                      
                    'uname1' => $uname1,
                    'uemail1' => $uemail1,
                    'upass1' => $upass1,
                    'language1' => $language1,
                    'gender1' => $gender1,
                    'ustate1' => $ustate1,
                    'file1' => $finalimg
                    );
 $form_insert1=$wpdb->insert($table_name1,$data_insert);
 if($form_insert1)
 {
    echo "<div class='container' style{ color:red;} >Form 
    Submitted Successfully<div>";   
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Create your array as per DB table.
Then use WP insert .

```
 global $wpdb;
 $order = [
            'product_id' =>'1',
            'discount' => '1',
            'total' => '1',
            'status' => '1',
            'payment_method' => '1',
            'payment_reference' => '1',
            'sold_by' => '1'
        ];

$wpdb->insert('DB_TABLE_NAME', $order );
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there are 2 mistakes in you sql string.

Think it should be the `$table_name` variable should be concatenated

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE" . $table_name . "(
id mediumint(9) AUTO_INCREMENT,
album VARCHAR(50),
artist VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY  KEY (id)
)";
```

and remove `;` on the last line.

Comment: this is wrong, you will end up with: `CREATE TABLEwp_imlisteningto`

Comment: Noted, but the creation of the table wasn't the issue, that worked fine.