# Count occurrences of a list of words -> Then update values in a WordPress table

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, count

I'm looking for multiple words in a text. I get the words from a wordpress table (LIST) where I have two columns (WORD and OCCURRENCES) with:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT WORD FROM LIST");
$data = implode('|', $result);
$val = "'/\b($data)\b/i'";
```

Then I use

```
if(preg_match($val,$text)) { UPDATE OCCURRENCES }
```

for searching, where

```
$val = "'/\b(word1|word2|word3!word4|word5|word6|...)\b/i'";
```

Now the problem is: How can I count and how can I get the number of occurrences for each one of the words, so as to insert this value into "LIST" table ? Is it possible ?

Thanks

EDIT
I explain better the goal I want to achieve if is it possible. This my WordPress Table (just an example):

```
|  ID   |   WORD   |  OCCURRENCES  |
————————————————————————————————————
|   1   |   word1  |       23      | 
|   2   |   word2  |       17      | 
|   3   |   word3  |        9      | 
|   4   |   word4  |        5      | 
|   5   |   word4  |       12      |
```

In the table there are over a hundred words. If I find a match, the code should update the "occurrences value"

Comment: I think the `$val` should look like `$val = '/\b(word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6|...)\b/i';`. And the solution might be [similar to this one](http://ideone.com/AjIQI5). Is it?

Comment: Thank you very much.
I updated the question more clearly

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) for this.
Try something like this -

```
$val = "/\bword1|word2|word3\b/i";
//Example text
$text = "word1 word2 word3 word3 word2";

//This matches all occurences
if(preg_match_all($val,$text,$matches) > 0){
    //This counts the frequencies of each occurence
    $res = array_count_values($matches[0]);
    print_r($res);
}

/*OUTPUT
[
     "word1" => 1
     "word2" => 2
     "word3" => 2
]
*/
```

Comment: Thank you, the road to the solution is right.
I updated the question more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution based on capturing the words into group 1, and then counting each key occurrence in it with `array_count_values`:

```
$text = "word1 word4 word4 word6 word6 word6";
$val = '/\b(word1|word2|word3|word4|word5|word6)\b/i'; 
$arr = array();
if(preg_match_all($val,$text, $matches) > 0) {
    $arr = array_count_values($matches[1]);
    if ($arr["word1"] != NULL) { echo $arr["word1"] . PHP_EOL; };
    if ($arr["word2"] != NULL) { echo $arr["word2"] . PHP_EOL; };
    if ($arr["word3"] != NULL) { echo $arr["word3"] . PHP_EOL; };
    if ($arr["word4"] != NULL) { echo $arr["word4"] . PHP_EOL; };
    if ($arr["word5"] != NULL) { echo $arr["word5"] . PHP_EOL; };
    if ($arr["word6"] != NULL) { echo $arr["word6"] . PHP_EOL; };
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/t811GJ)

**Note** that if you do not place the words into a group (I decided to use a capturing one), the word boundaries will have to be repeated and `$matches[0]` would hold the values:

```
/\bword1\b|\bword2\b|\bword3\b/i
```

Comment: Thanks for your time,  I updated the question more clearly.

Comment: Please check if [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11205932/3832970) and [this post helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29687037/3832970).